# Cell is not configured in collection view with Diffable data source, while using generics

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

I have four models: Vegetables, Fruits, Herbs and Condiments. Each model has separate collection view, and different cell identifier.
Data is successfully fetched which I confirmed by printing number of objects.

I have used DiffableDataSource, where data source is initialized as follows:

**Data Source & snapshot:**

```
var dataSource: UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, NSManagedObjectID>?
typealias DataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<String, NSManagedObjectID>
typealias Snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<String, NSManagedObjectID>
```

**Setting up data source:**

```
private func setupDataSource<T:NSManagedObject>(for collectionView:UICollectionView,
                                    with identifier: String,
                                    of entity: T.Type)
                                    ->DataSource
    {
        
         let dataSource = DataSource(
            collectionView: collectionView,
            cellProvider: {(collectionView, indexPath, managedObjectID) -> UICollectionViewCell? in

          let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! KitchenCollectionViewCell
        
        if let pantry = try? self.kitchenCoreDataStack.managedContext.existingObject(with: managedObjectID) as? T {
          self.configure(cell: cell, for: pantry)
        }
        return cell
})
         return dataSource
    }
```

When breakpoint is set in above code, it doesn't go past this line:

```
cellProvider: {(collectionView, indexPath, manageObjectID)
```

**Snapshot code to reflect changes:**
extension KitchenViewController: NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate{

```
func applySnapshot(animatingDifferences: Bool){
    let snapshot = Snapshot()
    dataSource?.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animatingDifferences)
}
```

}

EDIT: Some unnecessary codes are removed.

Comment: The cell provider won't be called until a snapshot is applied to the data source.

Comment: @vadian. I have updated my code, with snapshot. Its extension of view controller and confirms to NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate. How can we initiate this Snapshot function?

Comment: `dataSource` should be initialized lazily as a non-optional property.

Comment: @vadian: I had problem passing model, when initialzed lazily.